# StageWebView with transparent background, is it possible?

Tags: flash, flex4, air, blackberry-playbook

I have a Flex Mobile Project with a View in it. I placed a background image on that view. Now I want to add a StageWebView on it to render an HTML file, in such a way that the contents of the HTML scroll while the View's background is visible. However, when the StageWebView gets rendered, it has a white background. I didn't find a Background property on it to modify. I tried to change the stage's alpha, but it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely this is possible.  I believe you need QNXStageWebView (not just StageWebView) and in any case it's provided as a native component, and does not get rendered in the Flash "display list".  It is told where to render itself and does so using a QNX viewport so you have no control over it except what it provides through its own API, which doesn't provide this feature.